# Bash: Read Typed Input w/ Tab Parsing Into Array, Then Use Array Elements 1-by-1 With Grep

Tags: command-line, bash

The title pretty much states it.  Right now I accept a series of separate lines and do separate searches woth each one.  Now I want to get down to a single line in, tabs used to separate fields, the fields into an array, then process the array as individual elements for separate searches.  Not at all familiar with processing through an array in bash:

```
     #!/bin/bash
 while :
 do
   HOLD=""
   > ~/tmp 1
   while : 
   do
  read -p "Find What: " WHAT
  if [[ $WHAT = "" ]]
  then 
    break
  fi
  HOLD=$HOLD" "$WHAT
  echo $HOLD
  grep -riHn "$WHAT" --include="* chm" --include="* htm*" --include="* pb*" --include="* txt" >> ~/tmp 1
   done
   if [[ $HOLD = "" ]]
   then
  break
   fi
   sort -n ~/tmp 1 > ~/tmp 2;awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1' ~/tmp 2 |sed '/\/Trash\//d' > ~/tmp 1;cat ~/tmp 1|less
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
IFS=$'\t' read -p "Find What (TAB Separated): " -a WHAT

for QUERY in "${WHAT[@]}"
do
  echo $QUERY
done
```

to read the input. Input field separator (IFS) is set to tab and the input is stored in the array WHAT. ${WHAT[@]} holds all the elements of the array.The quotation is used to avoid re-parsing of the fields by the shell.